# Sourcetree Resolve Conflicts by Theirs Issue

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to solve conflict by `Resolve Conflicts by Theirs`. But It brings side effect.

There are branch A and B.

**Merge B into A**

Only `B`'s changes are displayed. There's only one conflict in `Foo.swift`(no other changes displayed) and all `B`'s changes. So I simply click `Resolve Conflicts by Theirs` to use `B`'s code for the conflict and commit for `Foo.swift`.

**The issue is:** The other changes in `A`'s `Foo.swift` also be reset to `B`'s `Foo.swift`. That is `Resolve Conflicts by Theirs` not only change the conflict part what I can see only in sourcetree, but also the other changes sourcetree doesn't display at all.

**Merge A into B**
I can see all the changes from `A`, for the `Foo.swift` I can see conflict and the changes.

In my scenario, `Merge A into B` works. But I'm not sure when I can use `Resolve Conflicts by Theirs`, I should only resolve the conflicts manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched Google to see what resolve by "theirs" means?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Of course I know, the thing is I can see only conflict without other changes. Then how should know other changes?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a way to do this in source tree? If you are please remove the `git` tag and add the tag for source tree instead. Otherwise you might want to better rename the title of your question to reflect what you actually want to do.